# Mock a Class using PowerMock without running in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock

```
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test.class)
public class A {
    public static void main(String []args){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test.class);
        when(Test.foo()).thenReturn(true);
        B.foo();
    }
}
```

The implementation of B is something like this

```
public class B{
    public static void foo(){
        boolean f = Test.foo();
    }
}
```

I'm writing code to test `B.foo()` which calls `Test.foo()` I want to mock `Test.foo()` to always return `true`. But when I run this code it is producing an error `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock` . I do not have permission to edit class B or class `Test`. If I make the method in class A as Junit it is working fine. But I cannot running it as Junit as I'm running this on a lot of input. Is there is way to mock a method without the Junit?

Comment: If the answer worked for you do you mind accepting it (and giving the due credit)?

Comment: It did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- You are asking test to prepare for Test.class, instead of B.class.
- You are using mockito and powermock? You should be using

  expect(Test.foo()).andReturn(true);

instead of

```
when(Test.foo()).thenReturn(true);
```

Once done, you should call replay like:

```
replay(Test.class);
```